# How to achieve searching on unstructured data in Spring boot Elastic Search integration with MongoDB

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

**I am a newbie in elasticsearch and wanna know if the following case works for me**

> I wanna achieve search functionality on unstructured data, What I mean by that is I dont know what kind of fields does a model have, as you can see the image below I have a data property inside a model in which any kind of data can be 
>   [image: How can I achieve search functionality on this data model]
>
> I know how to connect mongodb and elasticsearch using mongo-connect but I dont know that requirement can be achieved or not?

Comment: If i understand currently you do know that `data` property exists but you don't know which fields are inside. am i right?

Comment: Yes exactly, I am not sure what will come from my front end because each model has unique properties but their core are the same.
What do you think if I save all those unknown fields as one giant string with spaces, Can i achieve the same search functionality ? @AssaelAzran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on you last comment.

Let's say for example that your `data` field mappings look like:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "data": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see we didn't insert field to our schema, elastic will do that for us when we will index the first document.

Insert a new document:

```
POST my_index/_doc/1
{
  "data" : {
        "adType" : "SELL",
        "price" : "2000",
        "numberOfRooms" : 20,
        "isNegotiable" : "true",
        "area" : 200

    }
}
```

If we want to search for the word `SELL` but we don't know which field is assigned to it then we could use the following query:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "data",
      "query": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "2000",
          "fields": [],
          "type": "best_fields"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

We set `fields=[]` meaning:

> If no fields are provided, the multi_match query defaults to the index.query.default_field index settings, which in turn defaults to *. * extracts all fields in the mapping that are eligible to term queries and filters the metadata fields. All extracted fields are then combined to build a query.

[We used multi_match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html)

The results we get:

```
{
"took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.2876821,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.2876821,
        "_source" : {
          "data" : {
            "adType" : "SELL",
            "price" : "2000",
            "numberOfRooms" : 20,
            "isNegotiable" : "true",
            "area" : 200
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Insert a document

```
POST my_index/_doc/1
 {
  "data" : "SELL 2000 20 true 200"
}
```

Then your query:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
       "match":
        {
          "data":"SELL 2000"
        }
   }
}
```

In spring using QueryBuilder

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("data", "SELL 2000");
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: what if I put all info inside data as one long string and do my search on it ? because some fields may not be required for searching for example isNegotiable is not interesting for us so that I can omit some fields @AssaelAzran

Comment: You can do that. putting a your values in one string (data field) . then simple match query on a specific value.

Comment: on a specific value ? it is one giant value I will search on whole string right? this way can be achieved the same searching functionality ? Am I right? @Assael Azran

Comment: Yes you are right  but it won't give you exact matches. see my update. scroll down till you see **UPDATE**

Comment: Let me try this out, I will let you know if works @Assael Azran. Thanks anyway

Comment: Ok. i added Querybuilder match query  java syntax to my answer.

Comment: My friend thank a lot I have solved my issue however, ve found another one with mongo db relationships, anyway thank you so much @Assael Azran

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202887/discussion-between-aliy-and-assael-azran).